Transparent textures do not render properly
I was using raylib and instead of partially showing the texture behind it's just black.
Output:

Expected output (made with an editor):

Here's my code:
       BeginDrawing();

            ClearBackground(BLACK);

            BeginMode3D(cam);

                DrawTexturedPlane(test, testPos);
                DrawTexturedPlane(mc, cam.target);
            EndMode3D();

        EndDrawing();

I tried switching lines DrawTexturedPlane(test, testPos); and DrawTexturedPlane(mc, cam.target); but it just made reverse. I feel like I know but I just can't search it or remember it.

This may help you. You need to properly set alpha blending and ensure that the texture have four channels: RGBA.

I remembered where I've seen solution to my question: https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Blending
I just didn't sort texture by their distance to camera. Here's the code if you want tp see it:
...
const float distMc = Vector3Distance(cam.position, cam.target); // position to the guys is constant
...
float distTest = Vector3Distance(cam.position, testPos); // calculate position to the test object
//draw
BeginDrawing();

            ClearBackground(BLACK);

            BeginMode3D(cam);
                if (distMc <= distTest) {
                    DrawTexturedPlane(test, testPos);
                    DrawTexturedPlane(mc, cam.target);
                } else {
                    DrawTexturedPlane(mc, cam.target);
                    DrawTexturedPlane(test, testPos);
                }
            EndMode3D();

        EndDrawing();

